# На ноутбуке не работает клавиатура при установке ubuntu на virtualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, bios

Дано: ноутбук Samsung, Windows 7, беспроводная мышь (работает), VirtualBox-6.1.4-136177-Win (русский язык), ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64 (русский язык).

Проблема: Не ставится курсор в форму для заполнения на последнем этапе установки. Никак не реагирует клавиатура при установке ubuntu на virtualbox.

Что сделано: Прошлась по итету в поисках ответа. Подключила проводную мышь с USB, клавиатуру с USB. Меняла местами в BIOS USB Legacy на disabled и обратно. Подключила Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.4 в VirtualBox. Не помогло.

Что сделано еще: В настройках применила все варианты манипулятора курсора с вариантами контролеров. Попробовала вариант указания английской версии вместо русской. Вместо ноута На компьютер попробовала установить, виснит, даже не дает до последнего этапа установки дойти. Посмотрела еще раз видеоролики, статьи по установке виртуалбокса, ubuntu.

Как решить эту проблему по пунктам.[image: Содержание]

Comment: Драйвер USB в настройках виртуалбокса на `EHCI` и `xHCI` пробовала менять?

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Добавила выше фото. Не активна возможность редактирования драйверов USB. Есть возможность это исправить?

Comment: Чтобы редактировать настройки виртуальной машины, её нужно сперва выключить. А вы сохранили её состояние в файл, оставив её включенной

Comment: Вы правы. Благодарю! Но не помогло. Испробовала оба варианта, затем повторила тоже самое с подключенной к ноутбуку клавиатурой USB, повторила это же с изменением в данных в BIOS с клавой и без. Примечательно то, что в момент загрузки ubuntu появляется на пару секунд черный экран с мигающим нижним подчеркиванием. Там клавиатура работает и с ноута и с клавы. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Ставить через minimal-install редакцию пробовала?

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. Попробовала Ваш вариант. При установке ноут шумно загудел, зависла установка. Пришлось закрыть машину.

Answer (score 2):

Решение проблемы: увеличение в VirtualBox Оперативной Памяти до максимально допустимого. Курсор заработал. Клавиатура работает при установке ubuntu. Благодарю всех за обратную связь.

Comment: Странно, мне хватает нетинсталла и 512 оперативы.